# Display a Text() with a foreground color based on a condition

Tags: swift, closure, swiftui

I decided to write a simple tab bar for macOS using Swift.

`tabs.swift`

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import Combine

class ViewRouter: ObservableObject {
  @Published var currentView = "home"
}

struct Tabs: View {
  
  @ObservedObject var viewRouter = ViewRouter()
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      VStack {
        if self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" {
          Text("Home")
        } else if self.viewRouter.currentView == "settings" {
          Text("Settings")
        }
        Spacer()
        
        HStack {
          { () -> Text in
            if self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" {
              return Text("Home").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            } else {
              return Text("Home")
            }
          }()
          .onTapGesture {
            self.viewRouter.currentView = "home"
          }
          
          { () -> Text in
            if self.viewRouter.currentView == "settings" {
              return Text("Settings").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            } else {
              return Text("Settings")
            }
          }()
          .onTapGesture {
            self.viewRouter.currentView = "settings"
          }
        }
      }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom).padding(20)
    }
  }
}
```

In `ContentView.swift`, I just display this using `Tabs()` in the `ContentView` struct.

In the `HStack`, I use two anonymous functions to give the text in the tab bar a blue color when that item is selected:

```swift
{ () -> Text in
  if self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" {
    return Text("Home").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
  } else {
    return Text("Home")
  }
}()
  .onTapGesture {
    self.viewRouter.currentView = "home"
  }
```

I also do this for the second item in the tab bar.

Is this the best (fastest and most concise) way to do this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a shorter and faster way, using [ternary operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html#ID71).

You could use

```swift
Text("Home").foregroundColor(self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" ? Color.blue: Color.black)
```

instead  of

```swift
{ () -> Text in
  if self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" {
    return Text("Home").foregroundColor(Color.blue)
  } else {
    return Text("Home")
  }
}()
```

However, with the advent of macOS Mojave 10.14 two years ago, users had an option to enable dark mode. So, unless you've explicitly disabled dark mode in your app, `Color.black` will blend in with the rest of your app bar. To prevent this, check for dark mode with `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle")`. If the user is using light mode, `UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle")` will be `nil`, and if it's dark mode, it will be `"Dark"`

```swift
Text("Home").foregroundColor(self.viewRouter.currentView == "home" ? Color.blue: UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "AppleInterfaceStyle") == nil ? Color.black: Color.white)
```

---

As @BenLeggiero has suggested, this is a much shorter way to do the above:

```swift
Text("Home").foregroundColor(viewRouter.currentView == "home" ? .blue : .primary)
```

Comment: You can check for dark mode with `@Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme`

Comment: Is there a reason to not use `Text("Home").foregroundColor(viewRouter.currentView == "home" ? .blue : .primary)`?

Comment: @BenLeggiero No, there's not. In fact, I'll update my answer right now to reflect that.